# Convert matlab.double array to python array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am using the matlab python engine to access data from my matlab projects in python. This works quite well, but I do have a problem to efficiently use the matlab arrays in python. For example I want an array from matlab, I use (eng stands for the matlab engine):

```
x = eng.eval(arg)
```

What I get is a matlab.double array which looks like this:

```
matlab.double([[1.0,2.0],[4.0,3.0],[2.0,5.0]])
```

Doesn't look too bad. Let's try to catch an entry:

```
>>> x[2][1]
5.0
```

Yay! How about a full row?

```
>>> x[0]
matlab.double([1.0,2.0])
```

.. well, at least it's a row, but I'm not found of the "matlab.double" prefix.. how about a column?

```
>>> x[:][0]
matlab.double([1.0,2.0])
```

Wait, what? I try to select all rows, and then the first element from each, but instead I get just the row. And in fact:

```
x[i] == x[:][i] == x[i][:]
```

So, basically two problems arise: Selecting a row brings me the unwanted "matlab.double" prefix, and selecting a column (personally more important) doesn't work at all. Any suggestions here?
What i did now, was to reread every value for itself and safe it into a new python array:

```
c = [[] for _ in range(len(x[0]))]
for i in range(len(x[0])):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        c[i].append(x[j][i])
```

This works, but there is one catch: It extremely slows the code down with growing data. And of course, it doesn't feel beautiful to reread every single entry, if they are in fact already stored in x.

Thanks for reading through this long text, I just assume I explain a little bit more since probably only a few people work with the python matlab engine.

Comment: `x[:]` just makes a copy of x, so the behaviour is as expected

Comment: Oh, thank you - I wasn't aware of that. But why does x[a][b] works, and for example x[0:1][1] gives an index error (x[0:1] works)?

Comment: x[0:1] has length 1 and so the only valid index is 0. Try it with a Python list.

Comment: The question you should have asked is, "how do I efficiently extract a column?"

Comment: Wow, that question helped a lot - I came across multiple ways to encounter this problem now. For example, this one cut's the time in half  `for _ in zip(*x): a.append(_)`

This is, however, still quite a lot of time just for the for loop. I also managed to get columns way faster with a simple: `x[0::len(x[0])]`, but then I have the starting problem: How to remove the "matlab.double(" prefix/enclosure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic approach, which I'm using productively now, also allowing me to round the values if needed (careful though, rounding takes more calculation time):

```
from math import log10, floor

def convert(self, x, ROUND=0):

    conv = []

    for _ in range(x.size[0]):
        lst = x._data[_::x.size[0]].tolist()

        if ROUND is not 0:
            lst = [self.round_sig(elem, ROUND) if elem != 0 and
                   elem == elem else elem for elem in lst]

        conv.append(lst)

    return conv

def round_sig(self, x, sig=2):
    return round(x, sig-int(floor(log10(abs(x))))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the input from the discussion below I managed to find a reasonable way:

```
c = []
for _ in range(x.size[1]):
    c.append(x._data[_*x.size[0]:_*x.size[0]+x.size[0]].tolist())
return c
```

This way the command takes around 0.009s instead of 0.045s from before. Using the zip function was around 0.022s. Thanks alot, the code runs 5 times faster now!

For clarification: `x.size[i]` gives me the size of the `matlab.double` array. `x._data` gives an one dimensional array of type:

```
array('d', [1.0,2.0,4.0 ... ])
```

Therefore it includes a tolist() method to get an actual list, which I needed.

Comment: This works, but I think it should be "x.size[1]" (without the "-1")? When I tried the above code I lost an element from the array.

Comment: You are indeed right, no idea where this is from. Anyways, I'm using a more generic approach now, which allows me to have the same type as the entered value, I'll post it in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much more concise (and Pythonic) way to extract a column using list comprehension, and it also gives you the output immediately as a list of Python floats:

```
>>> x = matlab.double([[1.0,2.0],[4.0,3.0],[2.0,5.0]])
>>> [d[0] for d in x]
[1.0, 4.0, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For new comers to this question, `numpy` is the way to go, and you can optionally convert to pure python lists from there:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.asarray(x).tolist()
```